# Can I treat Quartz groups like queues?

Tags: message-queue, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I am thinking about using Quartz and I would like to have each group execute 1 job at a time.  But all groups should fire in parallel. The reason being that I am connecting to physical devices that can only handle one socket at a time.

As far as I can tell I can have StateFull jobs which will only execute 1 of that job type at a time.  I can set the scheduler thread count to 1 to ensure that the scheduler only executes one at a time.  Each is not what I want but I might be able to achieve what I want be creating a scheduler for each group.

Is there a better solution than quartz for queuing?